# Listview.builder with images from server, laggy on mid to lower end devices

Tags: listview, dart, flutter, lag

Im building an app, which, on one screen, has a listview, with some images and text loading from the API. I am also lazy loading this, so only 10 items load at once, and tried our custom method for lazy loading, as well as this plugin: https://github.com/QuirijnGB/lazy-load-scrollview

And with both cases, the when im scrolling this listview, i get EXTREME  lag and delays.

Any solutions as to what I can do, to fix this? Because on higher end devices, and some midrange devices aswell, it works fine.

Comment: try with `flutter run --release`, in debug mode there is a lag in listview but in release mode, the performance is much better

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check if there isn't any memory leak because I'm developing a similar app so after loading around 100 - 150 items with images cached in memory it goes from 1-2mb to 6mb.

Also note that the debug release will always work slower compared to profile and release build, you can trying using them and see how it works.